# Django FormView vs CreateView

Tags: django, django-forms

What is difference between Django FormView and CreateView?

Only diffrence I see, FormView require ModelForm but CreateView doesn't.

Otherwise both does same thing creating an object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From Django-docs:

[`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview):

> A view that displays a form. On error, redisplays the form with
>   validation errors; on success, redirects to a new URL.

It can be used for various purposes and is not restricted to creating objects. A nice example would be using it as a contact form and sending emails **without** *creating records* in database.

[`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview):

> A view that displays a form for creating an object, redisplaying the
>   form with validation errors (if there are any) and saving the object.

The sole purpose of this generic view is to create objects. But it is not limited to creating objects. You can send emails from this view too (just like FormView)

If your `FormView` creates model objects, it is best to use `CreateView` and not creating a modelform, that's what generic views are for, reducing repetition.

Comment: Don't agree with  best choice,  for example most of time we don't want to display all model fields.

Comment: then you can just include only the model fields you want to display using the `fields` attribute.

Comment: What about having additional field(s) ,  for example combination of two models,  there are some others use case as well.

Comment: then you'll have to create a modelform. I clearly mentioned that you can use createview without modelform for generically creating objects. If you want to do something which is not done by createview, you can just create a modelform and override other methods of the view.

Comment: Yeah that's correct,  but in my opinion one works best over another based on the use case ;)